# Description of a method

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a description of a method, but I do not understand how to put it correctly.

```
    /**
 * Add an artist to Karaoke<br>
 * Find the end of the artist arrangement and add the new artist        to that position.<br>
 */

 public void addArtist(String name, String category, String image) {

  for (int i = 0; i < artistas.length; i++) {

    artistas[i] = new Artista(name, category, image);           

  }

}
```

But I do not understand how to complete the route of the arrangement.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Please do not use JavaScript snippets for non JavaScript code.

Comment: Can't you use a dynamic structure like ArrayList in java that would make your work easier

Comment: Keep a global ArrayList<Artista> array = new ArrayList<Artista>(); something like this and then you can easily do array.push(new Artista())

Comment: I can not use an arraylist, since my teacher wants to teach us the use of arrays, Is there no other way to fulfill the requirement?

Comment: There is a way you can use something like this artista = Arrays.copyOf(artista, artista.length + 1); this will increase the size of your array and then you can add element to it

Comment: Your code, in words, would roughly be: "for **each** array index, assign a newly created element to that index". Does that sound right to you? How would you put into words what you want to do? Do you know? If not, your teacher would be the person to talk to, not us. If you do know, creating the code from that shouldn't be *too* difficult. Since you didn't describe your requirements particularly well, we can't really help you as is, but even if you did, it would mostly come down to writing code for you, which doesn't help you all that much in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

I think your updated working solution would look like this

```
public void addArtist(String name, String category, String image) {
  artista = Arrays.copyOf(artista, artista.length + 1); 
  for (int i = 0; i < artistas.length; i++) {

   artistas[i] = new Artista(name, category, image);           

  }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP almost certainly does not want to replace every element in the array every time addArtist is called, as you've done here.

Comment: @Dukeling true, I agree his logic is wrong but I was only trying to address his issue about array overflow when he adds a new object. once he know the way of increasing his size of array then he can work on his logic and get the output in whatever format he wants..

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to find the first empty index at the end, it should be enough to check for `null`, because object arrays are initialized with `null`.

```
public void addArtist(String name, String category, String image) {
    for (int i = 0; i < artistas.length; i++) {
        if(artistas[i] == null) {
            artistas[i] = new Artista(name, category, image);
            break;
        }           
    }
}
```

Beware: The above code will not work anymore, if there's a `null` value somewhere inbetween two `Artista` objects in the array. In that case the new `Artista` will be inserted into that index instead.